# what is the ancestral relationship between dogs and cats and bears?

Tags: evolution

or Mr. person who may  have my answer,
     I would like to know the answer of my question so I can make a craft out of it and show my dog. I know it may sound silly, but biology is one of the very few things in science I'm good at, I would really like to know my answer when ever it is efficient with you.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tour). Your question needs some improvement to increase its chances of attracting a good answer. For instance, you should show that you've made an attempt at finding the answer yourself (for instance by Googling 'dog cat bear phylogeny' first and reading some of the links), and we don't need to know anything about your dog or your crafting intentions to answer the question :)

Comment: The same which is between you and your cat, and your dog and bear :P

Comment: @another'Homosapien' dogs, cats and bears are all *Carnivora* while humans are primates. So dogs and cats are more closely related than cats and humans are.

Comment: @Remi.b I ain't that good at classification. I just wanted to say that this would be the answer if you ask here without any research effort.

Answer (score 2):

There are online resources such as [tolweb.org](http://tolweb.org/Terrestrial_Vertebrates/14952) or [onezoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/) that allows you to visualize the tree of life.

Cats, dogs and bears are all *[Carnivora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivora)*. The Most Recent Common Ancestor (MRCA) between dogs and bears lived about 44.9 Million years ago. The MRCA between the lineage giving rise to both dogs and bears and the lineage giving rise to cats lived about 51.4 millions years ago. You can find this [ancestor here on onezoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/life.html/@=44565?vis=spiral#x134,y-85,w0.9077).

Depending on your understanding of of phylogeny, you might want to have a look at [Understanding Evolution > History of life](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/0_0_0/evo_03), a short introductory series of slides, to understand the diversity of life and understand how to interpret phylogenies.